# How not to rebuild an Overlay Widget for Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, overlay, flutter-animation, flame

I have a FlameGame widget and have 2 overlays.

- Overlay A (with animation)
- Overlay B (with button)

At some point in code I need to display booth overlays.

- Overlay A will disappear after animation ends.
- Overlay B will disappear after button press.

My problem is that if I press the button on overlay B before the animation ends on overlay A, it causes a rebuild on overlay A and the animation restarts. (it does not look nice...)

- Tried switching around the order in witch overlays are added. Only makes A appear behind B.
- Tried making A stateful. Still, the removal of B causes A to call initState() again.

Answer (score 0):

Until someone suggest a non hacky way, I solved it by:

- Adding a double? variable to the FlameGame component of which I am added the overlays to and in the initState() of the A overlay I check if the value is non null.
- If it is I set it and keep setting it every time in the addListener() of the animation.
- If it is non null, I set my animation value to that value.
- In the dispose() I set the double? to null.

It is messy, but if anyone will need solution to this exact problem, I will try to provide the code.